# line-botのsignature（署名）とは

Tags: python, flask, line

以下の記事を参考にpython+flask+herokuでline-botを作ろうと考えています。
[FlaskでLINE botを実装し，herokuにdeployするまで](https://qiita.com/suigin/items/0deb9451f45e351acf92)

herokuでのデプロイも成功したのですが自分のスマホからメッセージを送信しても既読がつくだけです。`heroku logs --tail`でエラーを確認してみたところしっかりcallback関数は呼ばれておりlineと自分のコードが紐付いていることは確認できます。また、try構文でエラーをlogに印刷してみたところ

```
 ('Invalid signature. hogehogehogehogehogehogehogehoge',)
```

となっていました。このことから自分の署名がうまく通っていない、と考えることができると思うのですがここからの解決策が見つかりません。どなたかわかる方、教えてください。

自分のpythonの`main.py`は以下の用になります。

```
from flask import Flask, request, abort

from linebot import (
    LineBotApi, WebhookHandler
)
from linebot.exceptions import (
    InvalidSignatureError
)
from linebot.models import (
    MessageEvent, TextMessage, TextSendMessage,
)
import os

app = Flask(__name__)

#環境変数取得
CHANNEL_ACCESS_TOKEN = "hogehoge"
CHANNEL_SECRET = "fugafuga"

line_bot_api = 
LineBotApi(channel_access_token=CHANNEL_ACCESS_TOKEN)
handler = WebhookHandler(channel_secret=CHANNEL_SECRET)

@app.route("/callback", methods=['POST'])
def callback():
    # get X-Line-Signature header value
    signature = request.headers['X-Line-Signature']

    # get request body as text
    body = request.get_data(as_text=True)

    app.logger.info("Request body: " + body)

    # handle webhook body
    try:
         handler.handle(body, signature)

    except Exception as e:

        #abort(400)
        print(e.args)
        pass

    return 'OK'

@handler.add(MessageEvent, message=TextMessage)
def handle_message(event):
    line_bot_api.reply_message(
        event.reply_token,
        TextSendMessage(text=event.message.text))

if __name__ == "__main__":
#    app.run()
    port = int(os.getenv("PORT", 5000))
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=port)
```

Comment: Qiitaの記事を参考にして作っているようですが、そこの記事にある`ngrok`を使ったテストをしてみた結果はどうなりましたか？